# FTP bash script for iSeries AS400 from linux

Tags: linux, bash, command, backend, ibm-midrange

I have a bash script in a nodejs back-end application and I need it to execute an Iseries as400 instruction via FTP

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

host='www.hosting.com'
user='username'
pass='password'

ftp -inv $host << EOF

user $user $pass

QUOTE RCMD CHGUSRPRF USRPRF(USEREXAMPLE) STATUS(*DISABLED)

bye

EOF
```

The problem is that when executing it, it returns this:

```
ftp> QUOTE RCMD CHGUSRPRF USRPRF(INT0000279) STATUS(*ENABLED)
**?Invalid command**
ftp>
```

If i run the script from windows it works, but it fails on linux

Should I install any dependencies on linux for it to run successfully?

I appreciate your help

Comment: What distribution of linux are you testing this on?

Comment: hi @prieber the distribution is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft x86_64)

Comment: Please be more precise. Do I understand correct: You are running this *from* Windows *to* IBM i with (expected) correct outcome. When you run it *from* the Linux Subsystem within Windows *to* IBM i, it fails? Also, your mention of Node but showing a plain shell script is confusing. Please clarify your question.

Comment: If I run it in a Windows Terminal it works correctly

If I run it from (WSL) Windows Server Linux it fails resulting in: "invalid command"

The mention about nodejs is because the bash will be run from nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftp works for me from a bash command line to the ibm i:

```
steve@DESKTOP-MQ27OQB:/mnt/c/Users/srich/downloads/steve$ ftp 172.16.1.254
Connected to 172.16.1.254.
220 Connection will close if idle more than 5 minutes.
Name (172.16.1.254:steve): srichter
331 Enter password.
Password:
230 SRICHTER logged on.
Remote system type is .
ftp> quote rcmd sndmsg msg(abc) tousr(*sysopr)
250 Command sndmsg msg(abc) tousr(*sysopr) successful.
ftp> quote rcmd chgusrprf usrprf(srichter) status(*enabled)
550-Error occurred on command chgusrprf usrprf(srichter) status(*enabled).
550 *SECADM required to create or change user profiles..
```

Can you run FTP, outside of the bash script, one command at a time?

Comment: I already run it out of the bash, getting the same result in both cases

in Windows 10 Terminal it works

In a (WSL) "Windows Server Linux" returns "invalid command"

Comment: comparing your example commands with the commands that the administrator of the IBM server gave me, change the sentences from uppercase to lowercase and it worked, I will investigate if that generates some complications but I doubt it, I will also insist to the administrator of the IBM server to change the port and so connect via SSH and apply the commands from there as it should be, thank you all for your contributions

Comment: I should have seen that you had QUOTE in upper case.  And yes, SCP can be used to copy file to ibm i.  Just make sure to run "strtcpsvr *SSHD" in case the *sshd server is not started.

Answer (score -3):

FTP is a file transfer protocol.  If you want to execute commands you need to use SSH.

Your error isn't a linux or bash error, it's an ftp error.  ftpd (FTP daemon) does not speak AS400.

Connect via ssh, and enter valid commands in the shell you're given on the AS400 machine. Something like:

```
ssh user@server command
```

This would connect to the host named 'server' as 'user' and execute 'command'.  You should research `ssh`, perhaps google `man ssh` for an online version of the man file.

Comment: The IBM i FTP Server knows the RCMD site command for running CL commands in abundance of rsh or ssh.

Comment: Standard ftp functionality allows the client to tell the server to run a command.  This is a well known potential security hole on the ibm I.